# Shared element transitions not working when using FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Tags: android

So I have a pretty complicated navigation system where I can end up with cycles between the root activity and other activities. In order to avoid memory leaks I have to use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` when starting the root activity again.

To transition between activities I am using shared element transitions (ImageViews), which work fine when going from the root activity to other activities (in this case I am actually just using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`).

The problem is when restarting the main activity from other activities. Using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` in the intent causes the background to flicker to the phone home screen (the root activity becomes completely transparent and you can see the home screen) while the transition is ongoing.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(parent, RootActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(parent, imageView,     imageView.getTransitionName());
    startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

In the root activity I have a fragment so I have to call `postponeEnterTransition()` in `onCreate` and I call `startPostponedEnterTransition()` in the `onPreDraw` listener of the fragments root view.

I can't figure out what the issue can be. Is this a theme related problem or is it some bug in Android?

Comment: It's been long but did you happen to find a solution to this problem? I am stuck in a similar situation.

Comment: @PuruPawar sorry I have moved away from the project some time ago, but if I remember correctly the solution was to not use shared element transitions and just implement a custom transitions solution. If you only need scaling and translation it should be easy to do.

Comment: Thanks, @gookman. I was thinking about going all custom over this.