# Shared element transitions not working when using FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-animation, android-transitions

I am working on a feature that uses the SharedElement transition. In my application, I use the following flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT to reuse an existing instance of an activity.

> **Example -:** I traverse from Activity *A->B->C->D* then I want to open
> Activity B.
> The resultant stack will be *A->C->D->B*
>
> **Issue -:** When using the above mechanism in terms of the shared element
> transition animation the animation does not seem to work.

It does work when I create a new instance of Activity B, but then there are dual instances of Activity B in the Activity Stack. Which I do not want.

> I also require other activity instances that are in the backstack so
> clearing the stack won't be helpful.

I have visited the following posts related to this issue, none of them seem to have an answer to this issue.

- [Shared Element Transition when reopening existing Activity in stack Reorder To Front](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33168580/shared-element-transition-when-reopening-existing-activity-in-stack-reorder-to-f)
- [Shared element transitions not working when using FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39351927/shared-element-transitions-not-working-when-using-flag-activity-clear-top)

It would be really helpful if anyone could give me directions in going ahead with this issue.

Comment: Do you also use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP?

Comment: @harrytmthy no I only use the FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT flag.